# Provide hilt and dagger injection in one class. Hilt and dagger in one project

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt, inject

I have main DI as dagger framework, but some implementation made by Hilt framework.

But I need to use in one class Injections which made from both framework.

```
public class MainActivity{
    @Inject
    protected DataSource.Factory datasource;  //hilt framework
    @Inject
    protected DataProvider dataProvider;  //dagger
}
```

but I have an error from dagger MailAppComponent, because MailAppComponent contains

`void inject(MainActivity activity);`

and dagger tries to inject DataSource.Factory and Module which responsible for dagger providers does not contains DataSource.Factory

How can I exclude DataSource.Factory from dagger injection?